# Should I use `.toPrecision()` instead of rounding & exponentiation?

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I mean,

should I use this clean code...

```
var rounded=num.toFixed(n);
```

... instead of this ugly code...

```
var pow10=Math.pow(10,n),
    rounded=''+Math.round(num*pow10)/pow10;
```

even if the second one is much faster? ( http://jsperf.com/round-numbers-number-decimals/2 )

And why the first one is so slow? Couldn't browsers implement the second code for the first one?

Comment: Well the thing is they're not at all the same, and not really even comparable; `toFixed()` returns a **string**.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. I have fixed the jsperf and the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific use case where speed over a great number of iterations is necessary, I'd stick with `.toFixed()` because it's simple and easy to read and understand what you're doing. If you must optimize for speed, though, at least you know where you can start!

Comment: +1, I don't think it's possible to compare the difference in both example, so I will use first one.